# How to solve issue with fixture not found in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to use the pytester fixture, to create some files in the test directory, but I get the following error:

```
  def test_something(pytester):
E       fixture 'pytester' not found
>       available fixtures: _configure_application, _monkeypatch_response_class, _push_request_context, accept_any, accept_json, accept_jsonp, accept_mimetype, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, class_mocker, client, client_class, config, cov, doctest_namespace, live_server, mock_sparql_endpoint, mocker, module_mocker, monkeypatch, no_cover, package_mocker, pytestconfig, quotation_access_db_columns, quotation_access_db_path, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, request_ctx, session_mocker, sparql_query1, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

The code I am trying to run, to create some python files in below, taken from the pytester documentation:

```
def test_something(pytester):
    # Initial file is created test_something.py.
    pytester.makepyfile("foobar")
    # To create multiple files, pass kwargs accordingly.
    pytester.makepyfile(custom="foobar")
    # At this point, both 'test_something.py' & 'custom.py' exist in the test directory.
```

How can I use the pytester fixture to create some files in the test directory?
The link for the pytester documentation:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.Pytester.path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line in conftest.py (or in your test file) as [documented](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytester).

```
pytest_plugins = "pytester"
```

Or if you already have any existing one, just [make it a list](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/writing_plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file):

```
pytest_plugins = [
    ...
    "pytester",
]
```

Also, make sure that your version of [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) is >= 6.2 as it is the requirement based on the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytester).

Comment: Tried adding it, in the conftest and also in the test file. Getting the same error.

Comment: I updated my answer to include checking of pytest version if it is at least 6.2. Could you check?

Comment: Thanks, the version was the issue. I had an older version. The test was successful, but there is no file created. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: I tried and it isn't saved in the current path but to a temporary path. You can view it by displaying the value of [`print(pytester.path)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.Pytester.path) and going to that directory to see the files. Mine was `/tmp/pytest-of-nponcian/pytest-17/test_something0`. I assume they are flushed upon restarts :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to create the files in the current test directory?

Comment: I haven't tried yet but perhaps you can look into [tmp_path](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html) as it is used for the temporary files in pytest.